# Unable to read .xlsx file with Apache POI

Tags: java, soap, apache-poi

I have written the below code in a webmethod of a SOAP webservice. The below code is used to read .xlsx file, however the code jumps to finally block and does not throw any exceptions.

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        File excel = new File("Sample.xlsx");
        fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        System.out.println("Can read: "+excel.canRead()); //true
        System.out.println("Absolute path: "+excel.getAbsolutePath()); //returns correct file path
        System.out.println("is File: "+excel.isFile());  //true
        System.out.println("File exists: "+excel.exists());  //true
        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis); //The control goes to the finally block
        XSSFSheet headerDataSheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
        ........
     }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }finally{
        System.out.println("Cache Map DataSize---"+cacheMap.size());
        .....
     }
```

I have used the following jars.
axis.jar, commons-discovery-0.2.jar, commons-fileupload-1.3.2.jar, commons-io-1.3.2.jar, commons-logging.jar, commons-net-3.6.jar, jaxrpc.jar, poi-3.8.jar
poi-ooxml-3.8.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-beta5.jar 
 I have tried to update poi jar versions after finding a similar post on stackoverflow, but even that didnt help. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could try to temporary export your method from the soap context and test it in a main method. To see if it's POI the problem.

Comment: Try to add `catch (Error e)` and see if something gets caught

Comment: Why are you using such old versions of Apache POI? What happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy Instead of Error I tried Throwable so the catch expression looks like :
catch(Throwable ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
But the control still goes directly to finally method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different approach try the following :

```
Xcelite xcelite = new Xcelite(new File("src/Untitled_File.xlsx"));
    XceliteSheet sheet = xcelite.getSheet(0);
    SheetReader<Collection<Object>> simpleReader = sheet.getSimpleReader();
    simpleReader.skipHeaderRow(true);
    System.out.println(simpleReader.read());
```

Import

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.ebay</groupId>
        <artifactId>xcelite</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

[Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ebay/xcelite/1.0.4)

Please note that this repo is no longer maintained. Here is the [link](https://github.com/eBay/xcelite)

Comment: I maintain a fork, it's available here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.xcelite.spreadsheet/xcelite/1.2.5 and the github is here: https://github.com/xcelite-io/xcelite

Answer (score 0):

I tried the approach proposed by @Xavier Bouclet and noticed that the below 2 jars were missing:
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
Now the code is working as expected.
Thank you everyone